# Tempo gasto com desenvolvimento de testes

Tags: testes, engenharia-de-software

Tenho receio de estar me preocupando demais com testes, já que estou gastando atualmente cerca de 40% do tempo do meu projeto apenas na criação deles.

Eu sei que quanto mais tempo eu gastar com testes, menos eu vou gastar para corrigir bugs.

Mas assim como existe a [Curva ABC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curva_ABC) para definir os itens de maior impacto em pesquisas econômicas e estratégias de negócio, talvez exista algum estudo análogo na área de desenvolvimento de softwares que calcule uma quantidade ideal de tempo que deva ser gasta com testes (já que, assim como apontado pela Curva ABC, a partir de um certo ponto o teste vai custar mais caro do que o próprio código que ele testa).

### Pergunta:

Qual é a fração de tempo ideal de um projeto que deveria ser reservada para o desenvolvimento de testes?

Comment: Não seria interessante perguntar também quanto tempo o desenvolvedor investiu em testes em seus projetos passados? As respostas (até o momento) foram boas, mas não clareiam muito para quem não tem experiência. Seria legal instigar a apresentar um número real, não só a "fração de tempo ideal".
O que acha?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## TL;DR

Não existe um número mágico para estimar o tempo gasto com testes, assim como não há uma solução mágica para o problema da estimação de software.

Há algum tempo assisti à [uma apresentação](http://www.thedevelopersconference.com.br/tdc/2013/saopaulo/videos/testes-felipe-freire) de um especialista em testes e, em suma, o direcionamento em relação a este assunto foi algo como:

> Use um número mágico a princípio e depois ajuste a proporção conforme sua produtividade e o nível de qualidade do projeto.

## Sobre estimação de software

Em minha pós-graduação, desenvolvi uma monografia sobre estimação de software. No momento em que escolhi este tema, acreditava que iria encontrar um método mágico para determinar o tempo das atividades de um projeto. Assim que comecei a efetivamente a pesquisar, obviamente eu percebi que havia acreditado num grande engodo.

Um dos livros mais interessantes que li sobre o assunto foi [*Software Estimation: Demystifying the Black Art*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735605351) de [Steve McConnell](http://www.stevemcconnell.com), cujo título já esclarece muito sobre a essência das estimativas: elas são tentativas de prever o futuro. Estimativas são chutes.

A consequência disso é que não existe, nem nunca existirá, uma regra definitiva para realizarmos a estimação das atividades do desenvolvimento de software. Na verdade, métodos "matemáticos" de estimação ([COCOMO](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_COCOMO), [Function Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_point)) acabam confundindo seus usuários no sentido de que estes acabam acreditando que, por se tratar de um método matemático e estatístico, o resultado possuirá em si mesmo [acurácia](http://www.dicio.com.br/acuracia/) garantida.

É por isso, por exemplo, que metodologias ágeis não usam valores absolutos para estimar, como horas e dias. As *story points* (pontos de história) são grandezas relativas que podem variar de acordo com a equipe, com o projeto e com cada desenvolvedor individualmente.

Então, cuidado com soluções mágicas que podem tentar lhe vender. Embora algumas técnicas de estimação *pareçam* melhores, na verdade ninguém pode afirmar *absolutamente* que determinado método é melhor. Fazer isto seria o mesmo que afirmar que você tem um método para jogar na loteria *melhor* que outras pessoas, mas o resultado é aleatório.

## Existe uma solução?

A técnica mais indicada pelos autores e especialistas em estimação é medir a produtividade. 
Individualmente, este é um dos principais objetivos do [PSP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_software_process) (*Personal Software Process* ou Processo de Software Pessoal). Tratando-se de equipes, um dos pilares do Scrum, a [Inspeção](http://blog.myscrumhalf.com/2013/04/os-pilares-do-scrum-inspecao/), deve permitir acompanhar o progresso e a produtividade da equipe.

Embora a estimação, seja dos testes ou de qualquer outra atividade do desenvolvimento de software, seja uma tarefa mais de intuição do que um processo científico, em geral observa-se que as estimativas ficam mais próximas da realidade futura quando nos baseamos em dados históricos.

## Estimativa x Compromisso

Um erro comum no dia-a-dia é confundirmos as estimativas com um compromisso por parte dos desenvolvedores.

Por exemplo, vamos imaginar que uma empresa decide estimar os testes com uma regra mágica de 50% do tempo de desenvolvimento. Mas os desenvolvedores percebem que estão gastando muito mais tempo codificando testes. Uma das reações comuns é tentar acelerar o passo ou escrever menos testes do que o planejado para não "atrasar o cronograma", como se a estimativa inicial fosse uma obrigação a ser seguida. O ideal seria revisar a estimativa inicial e não tentar se ajustar a ela, mas na prática...

> Frequentemente falta aos gerentes de software firmeza de fazer o pessoal esperar por um bom produto (*The Mythical Man-Month*, 1975)

## A qualidade é um fator determinante

A citação anterior foi extraída de um [artigo sobre o Triângulo de Ferro](http://luizricardo.eti.br/2013/09/entendendo-o-triangulo-de-ferro-porque-nao-podemos-ter-tudo/) que escrevi há algum tempo. Este conceito, o triângulo, é importante pois demonstra que a qualidade possui uma proporcionalidade com o tempo.

Isso implica em afirmar que mais qualidade exige mais tempo. Por isso, a decisão de investir em mais ou menos testes no início do projeto influenciará diretamente na qualidade final do produto.

## Diminuindo o tempo despendido com testes sem prejudicar a qualidade

O título parece contradizer o que acabei de dizer. Mas, se tomarmos o conceito de separação entre atividades essenciais e acidentais do desenvolvimento como faz Brooks em [*No Silver Bullets*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet), podemos dizer que, embora não haja como evitar os testes sem diminuir a qualidade, podemos diminuir as dificuldades acidentais da criação deles.

Isso pode ser alcançado de algumas formas:

- Treinando a equipe para melhorar a produtividade
- Usando ferramentas mais adequadas que facilitem a criação e execução dos testes
- Investindo na automação
- Usando tecnologias (frameworks, plataformas) que facilitem os testes

Comment: Interessante a resposta (upvote). Só senti falta (como comentei na pergunta) de um número baseado na experiência em projetos passados, ou seja, "nos meus últimos projetos investimos X % do tempo em testes".

Comment: @JoséFilipeLyra Infelizmente meus últimos projetos profissionais foram de correção e manutenção, então faz um tempo que não participo de um ciclo de desenvolvimento completo. Entretanto, o que posso dizer de atividades individuais nas quais tenho o tempo hábil, baseadas em métricas pessoais, é uma média de 1x a 1,5x o tempo de desenvolvimento para criar testes unitários efetivos *antes da codificação*, isto é, cobrindo cenários com valores limite e alguns erros, mais 1x - 1,5x o tempo de desenvolvimento para testes de integração após *a codificação*.

Comment: Notas: [1] o tempo investido no teste unitário *antes da codificação*, efetivamente diminui o tempo de codificação. [2] A proporção do tempo de teste varia de acordo com a complexidade da rotina/método. [3] Em resumo, posso dizer que o tempo total de teste (quando feito adequadamente) varia entre 2x e 3x o tempo do projeto. [4] Em projetos anteriores que não possuem testes unitários ou automatizados (alguns nos quais fiz correções), o tempo gasto com correções tende ao infinito, pois a taxa de erros nunca estabiliza, já que não podemos mensurar corretamente o impacto das alterações.

Answer (score 13):

Creio que isso vai depender do quão importante é a sua aplicação, e quais as consequências de um comportamento incorreto. Uma aplicação mais ou menos inócua (como um jogo eletrônico) terá menos consequência em caso de falha que uma que faça a contabilidade da sua empresa, que por sua vez será menor que um sistema que controla um aparelho médico.

Já ouvi falar em "dedicar 3x aos testes para 1x ao desenvolvimento" ou "contratar um testador em tempo integral para cada 2 desenvolvedores", mas isso não passa de *guidelines*, não substitui uma análise caso-a-caso do seu domínio de aplicação.

> a partir de um certo ponto o teste vai custar mais caro do que o próprio código que ele testa

Como falei, dependendo da aplicação esse pode não ser o limiar (*threshold*) mais adequado. No caso do aparelho médico, por exemplo, não importa se o teste custar várias vezes mais caro que o desenvolvimento, importa se o custo com uma falha (processos, idenizações, etc) for muito superior que o custo do desenvolvimento + teste (e isso sob uma ótica puramente capitalista, sem levar em conta a possibilidade de perda de vidas humanas).

> Eu sei que quanto mais tempo eu gastar com testes, menos eu vou gastar para corrigir bugs.

Testes não são a única (nem melhor) maneira de se prevenir bugs. **Revisões formais de código**, por exemplo, costumam contribuir mais para a qualidade de um software que uma quantidade numerosa de casos de teste (o ideal é que o revisor seja uma pessoa diferente do desenvolvedor [de um trecho específico]). Adotar boas práticas de programação também ajuda.

Em suma, **impedir bugs de aparecerem** é mais eficiente do que **detectá-los e procurar sua causa**. Não se esqueça que, mesmo que seus inúmeros testes de unidade e integração detectem um bug, você ainda terá que isolá-los e corrigi-los. A principal vantagem desses testes é detectar esses bugs cedo - e continuar monitorando o código à medida que o sistema evolui - mas eles não fazem muito para reduzir o tempo que você gasta com a tarefa de depuração.

Por fim, é bom lembrar que uma boa arquitetura do sistema pode ajudar muito em prevenir bugs, principalmente se seu projeto conta com uma equipe de desenvolvedoers numerosa. Quanto maior o **acoplamento** entre os diversos componentes da sua aplicação, maior a chance da mudança em um causar bugs nos outros. Se cada componente está sendo desenvolvido/modificado paralelamente por pessoas diferentes, esse problema se agrava. A extensão do "esforço preventivo" ideal é portanto maior num sistema desenvolvido por uma equipe grande (onde há o clássico problema da multiplicidade de canais de comunicação) que numa equipe pequena/desenvolvedor único.

Comment: "Como falei, dependendo da aplicação esse pode não ser o limiar (threshold) mais adequado.". Excelente! A qualidade do software (e em consequência a forma e a quantidade de testes) são requisitos que variam de aplicação para aplicação. O teste eventualmente custar mais caro que o código que ele testa não é necessariamente ruim: se o requisito é um software de alta qualidade, nada mais natural que investir tempo em dinheiro em coisas que aumentam a qualidade do software.

Answer (score 7):

Na verdade, a comparação não deve ser feita em termos de tempo gasto escrevendo o código versus tempo gasto escrevendo testes para o código. A comparação deve ser entre tempo gasto escrevendo o teste automatizado versus tempo gasto testando a aplicação de forma manual.

O ponto é: todo código que é escrito deve ser testado antes de ser entregue. E é praticamente impossível executar testes manuais efetivos após cada mudança no código (fora o fato de que um teste manual demora muito mais do que um automatizado).

Portanto, apesar de não existir uma receita mágica que te diga exatamente o que testar e "quanto" testar, diria que uma boa tática é ter uma ótima cobertura de testes em códigos que lidam com regras de negócios, uma boa cobertura de testes de integração para saber se os componentes estão comunicando corretamente entre si, uma cobertura razoável de testes de sistema (incluindo testes na interface do usuário), e uma cobertura pequena para testes manuais. No começo, o que é uma "boa" cobertura e o que é uma "ótima" cobertura vai muito do chutômetro, mas a partir do momento que você começa a ter mais experiência e dados reais, estes valores vão se ajustando automaticamente. Dados reais podendo ser, por exemplo, número de bugs encontrados pela área de QA e/ou pelos usuários.

Answer (score 2):

Na realidade como tu faz os testes antes de começar a programar acho que é questão de prática. Mas como tu vai estar escrevendo um código de melhor qualidade, tu não deve se preocupar com o tempo que tu "gasta" com testes, porque como tu mesmo disse não vai gastar com bugs, mas além disso tu estás pensando na desenvolvimento todo, então não é porque tu não está escrevendo o código do sistema em si que tu não está produzindo, isso é uma visão equivocada de quando se começa a trabalhar com TDD