# O que são testes de software? Quando devemos usá-los?

Tags: testes, projeto-de-software

Tenho lido outras questões sobre isso e vi que existem ferramentas de testes que automatizam, prevêem possíveis erros de um software/aplicação etc.

O que eu gostaria de saber é em que tipo de projeto/sistema/software/aplicação é essencial haver esse processo do desenvolvimento, o que, por exemplo poderia ser testado e alguma ferramenta que faça isso.

Essa questão fez com que me interessasse pelo assunto e é disso que me refiro: [Tempo gasto com desenvolvimento de testes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1992/tempo-gasto-com-desenvolvimento-de-testes?rq=1)

Comment: Já trabalhei com testes de segurança de software, um guia que é muito bom para começar (mas a maioria de seus métodos já foram há muito "burlados") é [esse](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30815/An-Anti-Reverse-Engineering-Guide), caso queira dar continuidade a testes de segurança recomendo esse livro: [Reversing: Secrets of Reverse Engineering](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0764574817/)

Comment: Seria legal quem domina o assunto ir orientando o Joao Paulo para deixar a pergunta mais fácil de ser respondida. Só se não for possível é que ela deveria ser fechada.

Comment: Uma orientação seria muito bem vinda.

Comment: De uma forma beeeeeeem geral, teste de software é o processo que garante que o que foi desenvolvido obedece o que foi projetado, agora existem muitas formas diferentes de se fazer isso, inclusive existe uma forma de se desenvolver softwares se baseando em testes. E use sempre, absolutamente sempre, os testes estão relacionados diretamente à qualidade do sistema.

Comment: Como uma boa resposta seria bastante ampla, recomendo a leitura deste artigo da IBM referente ao assunto http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/br/local/rational/criacao_geracao_planos_testes_software/

Comment: Muito boa essa matéria. Vou tentar reunir informações dela e de outras fontes para tentar eu mesmo bolar uma resposta.

Comment: Como posso tornar minha pergunta menos ampla? Acho que um exemplo prático de algo a ser testado já me esclareceria.